# Include python modules as part of program

Tags: python

I have a simple python program that uses numpy, and I want to run it in a remote machine where I cannot install numpy or anything else.

The code needs to run by executing:

> python myprogram.py input.txt

How can I add this module as part of my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) allows you to install modules locally, e.g. in the home folder.

Common practice is to maintain the list of requirements in a separate file, e.g. requirements.txt. Deployment looks like this:

```
virtualenv env_name
env_name/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

To run your script, simply use `env_name/bin/python` instead of the system `python`:

```
env_name/bin/python myprogram.py input.txt
```